# Jira Python Query Translator

Tags: python, jquery, jira

Hello I'm trying to input a dynamic query into my python script such as:

```
project = ASSET AND text ~ '10T
```

and get a static query out of it like this:

```
key = ASSET-XXXX or key = asset-XXXX or key = ASSET-XXXX
```

My current output is a string like this:

```
[<JIRA Issue: key=u'OPS-xxxx', id=u'123456'>, <JIRA Issue: key=u'OPS-xxxx', id=u'1233456'>]
```

Current script looks like this:

```
issues = jira.search_issues(sys.argv[1], maxResults=5)
print(issues)
```

So I need to put a dynamic query in the command line and get a static query out of it. So if anyone has an idea on how to get the above results. Either key = "issue" or get only the key=u'OPS-xxxx' portion from the string.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you are using the [jira-python](https://jira.readthedocs.io/en/master/) package.

So, what you are actually getting back is a [ResultList](https://jira.readthedocs.io/en/master/api.html?highlight=ResultList#jira.JIRA.search_issues) (basically works like a list) of issues where each issue is a object from the Issue class of the package.

For a single `issue` you can access its key with `issue.key` and build your static query, likeso:

```
# The dynamic query
dynamic_query = "project = ASSET AND text ~ '10T"

# Run query and retrieve a list of issues
issues = jira.search_issues(dynamic_query, max_results=5)

# Build static query
keys_string = ", ".join(issue.key for issue in issues)
static_query = f"key in ({keys_string})"
```

If you run the static query you should see the same issues as with the dynamic query:

```
static_issues = jira.search_issues(static_query, max_results=5)
```